# Handling async streams in flask with twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, twilio, flask-sockets

I have a basic flask app to serve twilio calls.
When a call is generated via twilio it goes to my `/test` http api.

In this api I'm generating a twiml conversation where the first thing that happens is a  verb just saying "hello world". Then, concurrently I start a stream in the background. I'm using `flask_sock` for handling websocket connections in my flask app.

Here is my flask app route function that gets executed when the twilio call starts

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
   response = VoiceResponse()
   connect = Connect()
   connect.stream(url=f'wss://{request.host}/stream')
   response.say("hello world")
   response.append(connect)
   response.pause(length=30)
   return str(response), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
```

Everything works when my stream is not async.

```
@sock.route('/stream')
def stream(ws):    
    do_something()
```

When I try to make my stream function async, like this:

```
@sock.route('/stream')
async def stream(ws):    
    await do_something()
```

I get `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'stream' was never awaited` And my socket gets automatically terminated (`ConnectionError`)

How can I make this work with async?

For extra context: I'm running my flask app like this and then just running `flask run`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

... functions described above

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I cannot **await** the stream function because I'm not calling it, it's just a websocket entrypoint for twilio to initiate..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this documentation helps, [TwiML Voice: < Stream >](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream).

Per the documentation,

> The < Start > verb starts the audio < Stream > asynchronously and
> immediately continues with the next TwiML instruction. If there is no
> instruction, the call will be disconnected. In order to avoid this,
> provide a TwiML instruction to continue the call.
>
> If you'd prefer a synchronous bi-directional stream, you should use
> the < Connect > verb.

So instead of `connect`, try `start`!